# macOS Sierra 10.12 : Homebrew can't brew upgrade Warning: We do not provide support for this pre-release version

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-sierra

Yesterday I upgrade macOS Sierra, When I brew upgade,appeared error:

```
     Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
     We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
     You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
     Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

I search long time for solve for this problem ,

eg:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

or:

```
 sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

And then reboot OS,there are still this problem.

> /usr/local exists already, it can be writed.

So,I don't  use brew upgrade, please help,I have a long time can't use it.

Comment: Perhaps you are stuck at the documented Upgrade Problem? did you checked the brew README https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/#update-bug ? else, did you ran `brew doctor`?

Answer (score 11):

I have same problem. This works for me:

Go to your terminal, type those command, change whoami to your username.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
xcode-select --install
```

You will give write permission to `/usr/local` and also you will download and install **Command Line Developer Tools** from Apple, it may take like 1~2 mins.

Try to run upgrade in case of you are seeing such error:`Homebrew: Error: update-report should not be called directly`

```
brew upgrade
```

Now do the update.

```
brew update
```

In the end you will see:

```
Homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local. If you wish
you can return /usr/local to its default ownership with:   sudo chown
root:wheel /usr/local
```

just do it:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local
```

Comment: Thanks, the steps as you describe solved the issue with my installation

Answer (score 10):

After trying everything else, the following code block finally did it for me ...

```
 cd "$(brew --repo)" && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master && brew update
```

This code came from the brew README https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/#update-bug.
After running it, this is what I got ...

```
  ==> Migrating HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY (please wait)...
  Error: /usr/local/Homebrew already exists.
  Please remove it manually or uninstall and reinstall Homebrew into a new
  location as the migration cannot be done automatically.
```

I ignored the final error message, and went on with ...

```
  MacDePadre:local arick$ brew upgrade
```

I had a bunch of libraries that needed to be updated, so it took a long time, but this seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
sudo xcode-select -r
Edit and set the date of your Mac as October 1st, 2019
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
brew upgrade
```

Answer (score -2):

You just have to upgrade to Homebrew 1.0.0 (1.1.0 or 1.2.0). Go to `brew.sh` and follow the instructions.

Comment: It is not a nice or useful feedback. We should take care many people is so lost and its hard for them to find answers to their problems.

I am a little bit skilled in this issue and it still as opened.

Answer (score -2):

Install Homebrew. The missing package manager for macOS.
This solved mine.

#### Steps:

1.Open Terminal.

2.Paste the line below.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

3.Hit return (It will do all of the processes by its own.
I Hope this may help you).